# Not able to delete \n

Tags: python, list, newline, sublist

Maybe a very simple answer but I cannot seem to get rid of a newline character.
I have a list that contains a list and it looks like this:

```
[['US', '  146465', '  146935', '  148012', '  149374', '  150822', '  152055', '  153315', '  154448', '  154862', '  155402\\n\n']]
```

At the end there are two newline characters and I need to get rid of them. So first I iterated thought the big list to arrive at the sublist.

```
for lists in L:
```

Now that I am there I want to get the last element of the list using `list[-1]` When I print this I get `155402\n` Where did the second newline go? So I continue, now I guess the only thing to do is split it at the newline right?:

```
print(lists[-1].split('\n'))
```

My output:

```
['  155402\\n', '']
```

What in the world! Now there is a a double slash before the newline. So turns out I am incapable of taking out a simple newline character:D So really my question is how can I get rid of a newline in lists of a list. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you want `strip()` not `split()`, `split` *splits the string by the separator and creates a list of the split portions*. `strip` strips the arguments from either end of the string, defaulting to all whitespace with no arguments

Comment: Nice thank you sir. Do you mind showing your explanation as an answer because I am not really able to execute this properly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another slightly different regex approach - you can catch both new line characters OR double backslashed `n`:

```
import re

for lists in L:
    lists[-1] = re.sub('\\\\n|\n', '', lists[-1])
```

Or out of a loop

```
L[0][-1] = re.sub('\\\\n|\n', '', L[0][-1])
```

Comment: Wow extremely helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The extra \ is affecting the split.  So what you need to do is replace the extra "\" with ""

Try:

`lists[-1].replace("\\\\", "\\").split("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

In the last item in the list, there is actually only one newline character, not two. The backslash "escapes" the newline character so there is only 1. It is not deleting the second newline character because there isn't a second newline character. Change `'  155402\\n\n'` to `'  155402\n\n'` if you want 2 newlines.

Comment: I see this is really helpful. You explain it and you don't give the answer so I can actually figure it out myself. I like this idea of an answer Thank You!